# set a pause in timeline between two keyframes in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I am currently working on a GUI for a card game and I want to make a pause between the two keyframes.

When the animation start, the card will move to the center of the screen. Then, it moves back to its pile at the end of the animation.

I have tried to add a new keyframe between the two keyframes to make a pause but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help to solve this question?

Here is my code

```
    Duration t1 = Duration.seconds(1);

    Duration t2= Duration.seconds(2);



    KeyFrame start = new KeyFrame(t1, 
              new KeyValue(imgView.layoutXProperty(), 700),
              new KeyValue(imgView.layoutYProperty(), 350),
              new KeyValue(imgView.scaleXProperty(), 2),
              new KeyValue(imgView.scaleYProperty(), 2),
              new KeyValue(backImg.layoutXProperty(), 700),
              new KeyValue(backImg.layoutYProperty(), 350),
              new KeyValue(backImg.scaleXProperty(), 2),
              new KeyValue(backImg.scaleYProperty(), 2));


    KeyFrame end = new KeyFrame(t2,
            new KeyValue(imgView.layoutXProperty(), 600),
            new KeyValue(imgView.layoutYProperty(), 10),
            new KeyValue(imgView.scaleXProperty(), 1),
            new KeyValue(imgView.scaleYProperty(), 1),
            new KeyValue(backImg.layoutXProperty(), 600),
            new KeyValue(backImg.layoutYProperty(), 10),
            new KeyValue(backImg.scaleXProperty(), 1),
            new KeyValue(backImg.scaleYProperty(), 1));

    imgView.setVisible(true);
    backImg.setVisible(false);



    timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(start,end);
```

Comment: It's not really clear where you want the pause, but to make a pause add two key frames with different times (the difference between the times will be the length of the pause), and the same values for the properties.

Comment: @James_D     I want the image move to the center of the  screen firstly and it stop there for a while and then move. Can I still use this method? Thanks a lot!